# List monthy archives for specific year with wp_get_archives

Tags: shortcode, widgets, archives

I just want a simple list with the monthly archives for one specific year. Like so:

- January
- February
- March
- April
- etc.

I don't need anything fancy like yearly grouping. Ideally I would like a shortcode like this [month-archive year=2019]. This is how far I've come but the 'Year' parameter does not seem to do anything.

```
function my_monthly_archives() { 

$my_archives = wp_get_archives(array(
    'type'=>'monthly', 
    'limit'=>10,
    'echo'=>0,
    'year'=>'2018'
));

return $my_archives; 

} 

// Create a shortcode
add_shortcode('month-archive', 'my_monthly_archives'); 

// Enable shortcode execution in text widget
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `year`, `monthnum`, `day` and `w` (week) parameters are only used to *highlight/pre-select* the current item in the list/output and they only take effect on an archive page like date and category archives. And by "highlight", I mean WordPress will add either `selected='selected'` (if the `format` is `option`) or `aria-current="page"` (for other `format` than `link`) to the output. Something like this (note the `selected` attribute):

```php
// Assume $results contains database's rows (row objects).
// And '2018' is in the $args you pass to wp_get_archives().
$output = '';
foreach ( $results as $row ) {
    if ( is_archive() && '2018' === $row->year ) {
        $output .= '<option value="2018" selected>2018</option>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<option value="2018">2018</option>';
    }
}
```

Try the following and visit any archive pages, and you'd see the year `2018` *option* is pre-selected:

```php
$my_archives = '<select>' . wp_get_archives( array(
    'type'   => 'yearly',
    'limit'  => 10,
    'echo'   => 0,
    'year'   => '2018',
    'format' => 'option', // this outputs an <option>
) ) . '</select>';
```

Other examples below, assuming there's a (public) post on November 1, 2018:

***And that you're on an archive page*** — on other pages like single posts, those four parameters (`year`, `monthnum`, `day` and `w`) default to the ones in the **main query**.

1. When `format` is `monthly`, `November 2018` would be pre-selected:

   ```php
   $my_archives = '<select>' . wp_get_archives( array(
       'type'     => 'monthly',
       'limit'    => 10,
       'echo'     => 0,
       'year'     => '2018',
       'format'   => 'option',
       'monthnum' => 11,
   ) ) . '</select>';
   ```
2. When `format` is `weekly`, `October 29, 2018–November 4, 2018` (week 44<sup>th</sup> in 2018) would be pre-selected:

   ```php
   $my_archives = '<select>' . wp_get_archives( array(
       'type'   => 'weekly',
       'limit'  => 10,
       'echo'   => 0,
       'year'   => '2018',
       'format' => 'option',
       'w'      => 44,
   ) ) . '</select>';
   ```
3. When `format` is `daily`, `November 1, 2018` would be pre-selected:

   ```php
   $my_archives = '<select>' . wp_get_archives( array(
       'type'     => 'daily',
       'limit'    => 10,
       'echo'     => 0,
       'year'     => '2018',
       'format'   => 'option',
       'monthnum' => 11,
       'day'      => 1,
   ) ) . '</select>';
   ```

So that `year` parameter won't give you the results you're wanting to have; however, it is possible to achieve the results using the [`getarchives_where` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/getarchives_where/) in combination with a custom parameter, like so:

1. This should go in the theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'getarchives_where', function ( $where, $parsed_args ) {
       if ( ! empty( $parsed_args['in_year'] ) ) {
           $year = absint( $parsed_args['in_year'] );
           $where .= " AND YEAR(post_date) = $year";
       }
       return $where;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```
2. Then when you call `wp_get_archives()`, simply use the `in_year` parameter to include only the archives for a specific year: (* You can change the parameter *name*, but also change it above.)

   ```php
   $my_archives = wp_get_archives( array(
       'type'    => 'monthly', 
       'limit'   => 10,
       'echo'    => 0,
       'in_year' => '2018', // custom parameter
   ) );
   ```

   But you can still use the standard `year` parameter to highlight/pre-select the relevant item.